# Samba - Restrict saving media files (MP3, AVI, JPG)

Tags: linux, samba

I am looking to move away from Windows for file storage for users, but at the moment don't see a way to implement file resource management like it is done in Windows Server, effectively blocking certain file types. (MP3, AVI, JPG)  I was hoping to use Samba but the closest thing I could find was the veto option but that only seems to hide the file, not deny it's write.  Is there a way to do this?  It doesn't need to be Samba, but another Linux alternative preferably.

Answer (score 1):

You can use 'veto files' option. By default it's off.

```
[global]
veto files = /*.avi/*.mp3/
delete veto files = yes
```

In global restrict write for any share folder you have. Or only public

```
[public]
path = /path/share
veto files = /*.avi/*.mp3/
delete veto files = yes
```

Comment: From what I have read that seems to just hide the files vs deny them being written to the file system. :/